# Search A sub-string in a string (case sensitive) in PHP

Tags: php, string, search, find, case-sensitive

Is there any methods on finding a substring in a string (case sensitive)?
most of the functions I search gives me the occurrence. BUt I need the word.

Ex. string is "I love you"
I search for "LoVe"

then it still gives me the "love" in my string.

Comment: You are telling case insensitive, but your example explains that it should be case sensitive. you need to find "LoVe" but the string contains "love". So, the function should return nothing, right?

Comment: my fault it should be case sensitive

Comment: `then it still gives me the "love" in my string.`? and where's your code?

Comment: Im not sure with my code but I tried this.

   $search = preg_match('/^a-zA-Z0-9/i', $_POST['search']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$string="I love you";
$search="LoVE";

var_dump(stristr($string,$search));  //Case sensitive
var_dump(strstr($string,$search));  //Case insensitive
```

You can use the returned value with `!==` or `===` comparison

**[PHP Manual: stristr](https://www.php.net/stristr)**

**[PHP Manual: strstr](https://www.php.net/strstr)**